# Use Hadoop SDK with local HDInsight Server

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

Is it possible to use the Hadoop SDK, especially LINQ to Hive, with a local installation of HDInsight Server. Note that I am not refering to HDInsight Service hosted on Azure.

I tried to use LINQ to Hive from Microsoft.Hadoop.Hive Nuget package, but was unable to get it working, because LINQ to Hive seems to require that results are stored in Azure Blob Storage, rather than on my hosted instance.

```
var hiveConnection = new HiveConnection(new Uri("http://hadoop-poc.cloudapp.net:50111"), "hadoop", "hgfhdfgh", "hadoop", "hadooppartner", "StorageKey");
var metaData = hiveConnection.GetMetaData().Result;
var result = hiveConnection.ExecuteQuery(@"select * from customer limit 1");
```

Even with a storage key, I cannot get this to work, because the MapReduce job fails with:

```
AzureException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container a7e3aa39-75ba-4cc2-a8aa-301257018146 in account hadooppartner not found, and we can't create  it using anoynomous credentials.
```

I also added the credentials once more to the `core-site.xml` file, as follows:

```
<property>
   <name>fs.azure.account.key.hadooppartner.blob.core.windows.net</name>
   <value>Credentials</value>
</property>
```

However I would rather get rid of storing results on Azure Storage, if possible.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HiveConnection constructor without the storage account options to connect to a local install. This works against a default install of the HDInsights developer preview on a local box:

```
var db = new HiveConnection(
            webHCatUri: new Uri("http://localhost:50111"),
            userName: (string) "hadoop", password: (string) null);
var result = db.ExecuteHiveQuery("select * from w3c");
```

Of course you can then use that connection for any LINQ queries as well.

Comment: I installed HDInsight but http://localhost:50111 url is not configured during the installation process. Is it something we have to configure after Hdinsight is installed? Please confirm

Comment: Check that that Apache Hadoop templeton service is running, that should open up on 50111.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I checked and Templeton service is running. from the command prompt I also checked "telnet localhost 50111" command to make sure it is not a firewall issue, and this port is open. Could there be any other issues, please suggest

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that in the `HiveConnection` constructor you have to specify the full storage account name, i.e. `hadooppartner.blob.core.windows.net`.

I am still interested to use the .NET LINQ API without the need for a storage account. Furthermore is it possible to use the .NET API with other Hadoop distributions?